# How to disable QR code generator in Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-edge, windows-11-preview

Using Microsoft Edge v92.0.902.78 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 11 and want to disable  QR code generator but can't since the flag documented in various support forums and blogs isn't available anymore. Or I can't seem to find it.

[image]

Example solution : [How to disable QR Code Generator in Edge](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/154911-how-enable-disable-qr-code-generator-microsoft-edge-chromium.html)

[image]

Comment: If the flag does not exist in order to disable/enable it then it probably cannot be disabled.  It does not appear a group policy exists that allows/disallows it.  The flag was also disabled for other chromium based browsers that have been upgraded to 92+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are asking to remove the "Create QR code" option from
the context menu of Microsoft Edge.

Unfortunately, this experimental option that was voluntary before,
is now no longer experimental nor voluntary.

Users have repeatedly posted requests for Chromium-based browsers
to be able to customize the context menus, but they have been
ignored by the Chromium team and also by the Microsoft Edge team.

There is now no way to remove anything from the context menu.
We are stuck with QR codes, at least for the moment.

Comment: I am going to accept this as an answer until there is a way to do it.